# Java Generate Random number {-1,0,1}

Tags: java, random

I need a function that will return a random integer that can be only -1, 0, or 1.
Thanks?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Apocalisp wrote, you could do something like:

```
import java.util.Random;

Random generator = new Random();
int randomIndex = generator.nextInt( 3 ) - 1;
```

Comment: Ha!  You beat me by seconds!  ;-)

Comment: Yes, it does.  I was hoping to edge out Justin with the javdoc, though.  Next time, I should just go for "First P0st!!!111!!@@One!!"

Comment: First post. Then edit it with pointless code and links to the JavaDoc (just in case anyone doesn't have their favourite JavaDoc location bookmarked). Then replace it with a paraphrase of the second person's correct answer.

Comment: Awesome! At least everyone else can be confident the code works since its the same one-liner :)

Comment: Oh I didn't notice you linked to the javadoc... :(. I voted for this guy cause he had the import statement, which I usually forget to do, causing me to waste 10 minutes trying to find the problem.

Comment: But I dont even think the import statement is needed here... w/e

Comment: Yeah, my two line solution was waaaaaay better because of the javadoc link....  ;-)  To be honest, I never ever think about import statements anymore.  Whatever IDE you're using (Netbeans or Eclipse at our office) will just import if / when necessary.

Answer (score 10):

How about generating a random from 0 to 2 and subtracting 1?

Comment: Thought about submitting an Enterprise solution, but it's proprietary.

Comment: Why not generate a random number from 17 to 19 and subtract 18?

Comment: @Bombe, you've opened the door to a very dark place.  Random number from 0 to 1000 modulus 3 - 1?  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

[This should help](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

```
Random random = new Random();
int value = random.nextInt(3) - 1;
```